# TypeScript create id type from object of objects

Tags: typescript

Let's say we have this typescript code

```
interface Animal {
    name: string
}
const animals: {[key: string]: Animal} = {
    bear: { name: "Bear" },
    lion: { name: "Lion" },
};
type AnimalId = keyof typeof animals;
```

In this case AnimalId has the type `string | number`

I want it to have the following type: `"bear" | "lion"`

I also tried this:

```
interface Animal {
    name: string
}
const animals = {
    bear: { name: "Bear" },
    lion: { name: "Lion" },
};
type AnimalId = keyof typeof animals;
```

In this case AnimalId does have the correct type of `"bear" | "lion"`, but there is no type checking on the animals object

I also accept solutions where `animals` is an array or a Map, I used an object in this case because that seemed to be the easiest approach due to the existence of the `keyof` keyword.

I don't want to manually define AnimalId to be `"bear" | "lion"` as in the real program there will be a lot more ids to keep track of and having to change them at multiple places is far from convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new [satisfies](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html) operator is made exactly for this purpose.

```
interface Animal {
    name: string
}
const animals = {
    bear: { name: "Bear" },
    lion: { name: "Lion" },
    dog: {} // error: Property 'name' is missing
} satisfies {[key: string]: Animal};

type AnimalId = keyof typeof animals; // "bear" | "lion" | "dog"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgG2QbwFgAoZM5EOTCALmQGcwpQBzEgXxIQHsRHk4GbDnrIAvARLlkAIwhwodfBSq1kAIgBC8qOuTsANFPI5gvJSup11AGTMg9h42QAm3FkvbIA9N+TQobkVkAAVAgAdoMABPZABySmo45GBRTFT6Vg4GODBUmGAIUXwAbQBrCGi6RmYQFgBdOnQsXHYAbhISGMi0IVwASRdxZAro7hhkbohxgT6RNp8-dTkFPQAfDVNedY03FnUSIA)

Answer (score 2):

The best option is to use the new `satasifes` operator in typoescript 4.9 and up :

```
const animals = {
    bear: { name: "Bear" },
    lion: { name: "Lion", tes: 0 }, // Error
} satisfies Record<string, Animal>;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgG2QbwFgAoZM5EOTCALmQGcwpQBzEgXxK+IQHsRGyOBmw56yALwES5ZACMIcKHXwUqtZACIAQoqibk7ADQzyOYPxVrqdTQBkLITUeSR6dAAyGXAeh-IAUSgoXigOBjgwYHoYYAhxACUIPigAEwAeRmYQFhd0LFwAPgBubjAATwAHFHzRAElUyWQAawhy3hhXKogOoRFcelLiIA)

If you are on an older version you could also use an id function to do inference:

```
const animals = makeAniumlas({
    bear: { name: "Bear" },
    lion: { name: "Lion", tes: 0 }, // Error
})

type AnimalId = keyof typeof animals;

function makeAniumlas<K extends PropertyKey>(o: Record<K, Animal>) {
    return o;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgG2QbwFgAoZM5EOTCALmQGcwpQBzEgXxK+IQHsRGyOBmw56yALzJsAawjpgAV0w449ABRFS5AEYQ4UOvgpVayAEQAhfVHPJ2AGhLlkOYPyMnqdcwBl3IOYOyJD0dAAM9sEA9NHIAKJQULxQHACU3GAAngAOKAqiAJIAJpLIclm8MCG5EFVCIrj0ANzcMIogCGAB0nByCsqq9AA8ANLIEAAekCDF4gAKyXlQ2aMQWQB86rx0AEoQfFDFY8EFuBtpBM7kUBBgilAgyLytxJzEJEA)